# Running trinity for de novo assembly

Tags: linux

I have a problem in running rnaseqtrinity, my command line is here:

```
/home/marziyeh/Software/trinityrnaseq-Trinity-v2.4.0/
Trinity --seqType fq --max_memory 4G --left /home/marziyeh/Data/RNA-seq\ data/Main\ data/paired_32_L3_1_trimmed.fq.gz paired_33_L3_1_
trimmed.fq.gz --right  paired_32_L3_2_trimmed.fq.gz paired_33_L3_2_trimmed.fq.gz --CPU 2  --output trinity_out_dir_32_32.fq.gz
```

but the following error occours:

> Error, cannot locate file: paired_33_L3_1_trimmed.fq.gz at /home/marziyeh/Software/trinityrnaseq-Trinity-v2.4.0/Trinity line
>   2429.     main::create_full_path(ARRAY(0x555a78a86df0), 1) called at /home/marziyeh/Software/trinityrnaseq-Trinity-v2.4.0/Trinity line
>   1159

Thanks so much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Look, your pramater of `--left` have a fatal error .
You command line indicates that your reads is paired end. But your path of left read have some problems.
1. Your should use `\` to instead of `/`.
2. Your command shouldn't have the space， and the space in linux means a delimiter.